# PHP session in logging in

Tags: php

the below given is my code for a simple login page using session...
since i'm new to php or any such languages i expect any one to correct my code yours faithfully Arunkumar

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['btnLogin']))
{
    $Uname=$_REQUEST['txtUname'];
    $pass=$_REQUEST['password'];
    $obj-> check_login($Uname,$pass);
    $result=$obj-> executec1();
    //echo'Query'.$query;
        //$result=mysql_query($query);
        //$row = mysql_num_rows($result);
        //if($row==0)
        if($result)
        {
        //  echo "username or password is incorrect";
        //}
        //else
        if(isset($_REQUEST['']))
         {
    setcookie("username", $Uname); 
    setcookie("password", $password); 
         }
    else {
        setcookie("username", "");  
        setcookie("password", "");
        }
        $_SESSION['username'] = $Uname;
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not the site where people check your code.

Comment: You should stop using mysql_query. it was deprecated before it was deprecated

Comment: please help me...atleast give me a code with session to replace mine

Comment: Have you started a session? Otherwise you won't be able to use session variables.

Comment: i've started it in database connection code..

Comment: you haven't specified the problem yet

Comment: Please see this link for reference http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html but please don't use mysql_query you can use mysqli_query or PDO

Comment: i've gone through it but i'm using mysql, not sqli@Siraj

Comment: my problem is dat when i login through one browser it's okay and after logging in when i copy the url and paste it in another browser it automatically loggs in...please anyone help me.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['login_id']))
{       
$login='';
$login_id=$_POST['login_id'];//username coming from login form  page
$password =$_POST['password'];//password coming from login form  page
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE  login_id='$login_id' AND password='$password'";   
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)> 0)//if user user_id and matches then it must show 1 coderun
{
$user_id = mysql_result($result, 0, "user_id");
$screen_name = mysql_result($result, 0, "username");
$_SESSION["session_user_id"] = $user_id;/*like this you can make  
different session */
$_SESSION["session_screen_name"] = $screen_name;
header("Location: home.php");
exit();     
}
else
{
$errormess = "Invalid Login ID or Password";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first start session with this

```
session_start();
```

or better

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
session_start();
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
$_SESSION['username']=$Uname;
}
```

Comment: since you have not specified your problem its just to tell you that you need to start session before using it and you should check before creating a session whether it exists or not

Comment: my problem is dat when i login through one browser it;s okay and after logging in when i copy the url and paste it in another browser it automatically loggs in...